# storing and retriving multiple strings to a single file

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

I tried to store the username and password(which are two strings) to a same file. The storing part worked well for me but there seemed to be some error in the retrieving part. I cant seem to find out how to resolve it. Can some one please help me... My code for storing and retrieving string to file is given below:

```
 public void startApp()
   {

     try{   
        File setFile=new        
        File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/code.rhn");
        System.out.println(setFile.getAbsolutePath());
        if(!setFile.exists()){

           //writing data to file
              FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(setFile);
              OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
              myOutWriter.append(PuserName.toString());
              myOutWriter.append("\n");
              myOutWriter.append(Ppass.toString());
              myOutWriter.close();
              fOut.close();
              startPocket();

          }
     else
          {


         //reading two strings from file
              FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(setFile);
              InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fin);
              BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
              String receiveString1 = "";
              String receiveString2 = "";
              StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        //storing string1 to temp1      
              receiveString1 = bufferedReader.readLine(); 
              stringBuilder.append(receiveString1);
              temp1 = stringBuilder.toString();
        //storing string2 to temp2                     
              receiveString2 = bufferedReader.readLine(); 
              stringBuilder.append(receiveString2);
              temp2=stringBuilder.toString();
              fin.close();


        // checking for identical username and password                     
              if ((temp1== (PuserName.toString()+"\n"))&&(temp2==Ppass.toString()))
                         {
                           startPocket();
                         }
                     else
                         startWrongWay();

         }
       }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "exception occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }  

    }
```

Every time i execute this code after writing inetial username and password, only startWrongway() is executed and startPocket() is never executed even when i type the correct user name and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are making basic mistake with comparing Strings. You are using '==', where you should use 'equals()'. In few minutes I will check if you have other issues in code.

And after checking you have 1 more issue. StringBuilder is not needed at all. Due to not correct using it temp2 is finally sum of login and password. Fixing this + making earlier said equals (but without "\n" inside) should make your code working.

Comment: Thanks alot friend. removing string builder worked for me. My code is now functioning well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `temp1.equals(PuserName.toString())` instead of `==`. If you use `==` you are comparing the references and with the method `equals`you compare the value.

Also, you don't have to compare with `PuserName.toString()+"\n"` because the method `readLine`don't include any line-termination characters.

Comment: I tried using .equals but the error still persists. I cant seem to find what it is.

Comment: Try without the StringBuilder. Just use: `temp1 = bufferedReader.readLine` (same with temp2). And in your if use: `temp1.equals(PuserName.toString() && temp2.equals(Ppass.toString())`. If still not working, maybe your toString methods are not well implemented.